# how to copy bits from minimized window's HDC?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i would like to copy entire client window size of some window to my HDC, but when the window is minimized the source of all color bits is always empty RGB(0,0,0);
How to do this without activating the window?

Comment: I don't have an experience with this so this may not do much for you or make sense. :) Could you activate the window "off screen" by setting the x,y coordinates to somewhere off the visible screen, grab the data, and re-minimize it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [screenshots of covered/minimized windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464826/screenshots-of-covered-minimized-windows)

Comment: I didn't work on it, so it's hearsay evidence, but a coworker did develop an app that captured windows, and it didn't work for hidden windows unless you were running windows 7 with compositing on. The app was abandoned as useless and never made public :)

Comment: Generally apps refuse to paint when they are not visible. They check that by calling `IsWindowVisible()`. With DWM, that returns True even when minimized to make AeroPeek work. Otherwise, no dice.

Comment: Yes... still no answer. but someone tell about internal windows painting buffer. so i am thinking how to catch it or disasm functions like BitBlt to try capture this data..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
BOOL PrintWindow(
    HWND hwnd,
    HDC hdcBlt,
    UINT nFlags);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx